# A private API for iOS to kill other application

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Do you know any private API for iOS  which will allow to kill (not suspend) other application?

I am fine with private API, but it should work on jailed device.

Usual disclaimer: This is for inhouse enterprise app. I know it won't be accepted in AppStore.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish, but perhaps a management [solution](http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/apple-ios) suits you best.

Comment: Thanks. MDM won't solve my current need. I need to be able in runtime to make a decision whether to kill other app or not. MDM doesn't provide such functionality and also MDM is relatively slow (it takes time for push notification to get to the device, so it will go to the server and get  some new commands)